# Add shape to global zone, not local in Orchard

Tags: c#, orchardcms

**Problem in short:**

I've created a new content part and want to show this in a different zone, LeftPanel, which resides outside the main Content zone. This isn't working as it appears I can only add the contentpart to the local zones within the Content zone.
How can I add the contentpart to a different Zone on the page?

**Longer explanation:**

Our team has created a new Orchard website and have created a layout for it.
There are several Zones available and most of them are visible on all pages. These are all the zones available in the theme:

`Zones: Header, Navigation, Content, LeftPanel, RightPanel, Toolbar, Messages, Address, Footer, Copy`

I've created a new contentpart and attached it to the contenttype Page. With this contentpart it's possible to add banners to a page.
The implemantation is rather simple and everything appears to be working properly when I place them in the Content zone.

The relevant code I placed in the Driver is the following:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(BannerPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
return ContentShape("Parts_Banner", 
                        () => shapeHelper.Parts_Banner(
                                    FirstImageTitle: part.FirstImageTitle,
                                    FirstImageLocation: part.FirstImageLocation,
                                    FirstImageNavigationUrl: part.FirstImageNavigationUrl,
                                    SecondImageTitle: part.SecondImageTitle,
                                    SecondImageLocation: part.SecondImageLocation,
                                    SecondImageNavigationUrl: part.SecondImageNavigationUrl,
                                    ThirdImageTitle: part.ThirdImageTitle,
                                    ThirdImageLocation: part.ThirdImageLocation,
                                    ThirdImageNavigationUrl: part.ThirdImageNavigationUrl
                                    ));
}
```

Having the following text in the placement.info file:

```
<Placement>
    <Place Parts_Banner="Content:before"/>
    <Place Parts_Banner_Edit="Content:7"/>
</Placement>
```

This places the banners (of the contentpart) before the content.

However, I want the contentpart to be rendered in the `LeftPanel` zone. Changing the placement.info to the following:

```
<Placement>
    <Place Parts_Banner="LeftPanel:1"/>
    <Place Parts_Banner_Edit="Content:7"/>
</Placement>
```

Doesn't appear to have any effect, it's not rendered on the page anymore.

After having researched this issue for a bit I stumbled across [Bertrand Le Roy's blogpost which does something similar with an Amazon buy-now part](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/26/dispatching-orchard-shapes-to-arbitrary-zones.aspx).

I've played around with the `IWorkContextAccessor`, but haven't had any success placing the 
contentpart in the `LeftPanel` zone.
The following code doesn't work:

```
protected override DriverResult Display(BannerPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    var shape = shapeHelper.Parts_Banner(
        FirstImageTitle: part.FirstImageTitle,
        FirstImageLocation: part.FirstImageLocation,
        FirstImageNavigationUrl: part.FirstImageNavigationUrl,
        SecondImageTitle: part.SecondImageTitle,
        SecondImageLocation: part.SecondImageLocation,
        SecondImageNavigationUrl: part.SecondImageNavigationUrl,
        ThirdImageTitle: part.ThirdImageTitle,
        ThirdImageLocation: part.ThirdImageLocation,
        ThirdImageNavigationUrl: part.ThirdImageNavigationUrl
        );


    _workContextAccessor.GetContext().Layout["LeftPanel"].Add(shape, 10);

    return new DriverResult();
}
```

It appears Clay is creating a new (zone?) object with empty properties. Somehow, Orchard can't find this zone. I suspect it has something to do with **global zones** and **local zones**, but I could be wrong of course.

Enumerating through the zones also doesn't work, as it doesn't have a GetEnumerator() method, this will create an exception.

```
foreach (var zone in _workContextAccessor.GetContext().Layout.Zones)
{
    _workContextAccessor.GetContext()
                        .Layout.Zones[zone]
                        .Add(shape, 1);
}
```

I'm probably missing something from Bertrand's post. I see he's creating a Model which has the Zones property and uses that, but I can't figure out how that should be working (even after looking through the solution he has in supplied in his blogpost)

The Content template looks like this:

```
<article class="content-item @contentTypeClassName">
    <header>
        @Display(Model.Header)
        @*@if (Model.Meta != null) {
        <div class="metadata">
            @Display(Model.Meta)
        </div>
        }*@
    </header>
    @Display(Model.Content)
    @if(Model.Footer != null) {
    <footer>
        @Display(Model.Footer)
    </footer>
    }
</article>
```

I discovered that when I modify the `placement.info` to use the `Content` or `Footer` zone, it appears to be working. This however isn't very true though. When I use the `Footer:before` notation, it places the banners before the `<footer>` of the `Content` zone, so not before the real `Footer` zone, which resides outside the `Content` zone.

Any advice or solution on how I should fix this, so I can place this contentpart to a different zone on the page?

Comment: Possible answer(if not, at least it could be useful): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786291/orchard-cms-do-i-have-to-add-a-new-layer-for-each-page-when-the-specific-conten

Comment: The answer in that question works like charm. Also helpfull is randompete's post here: http://downplay.co.uk/tutorials/clay/part-2-through-the-looking-glass

Comment: Just came across this and it looks like the answer in MiBu's link is outdated. The correct syntax to push to a global zone from placement.info: `<Place Shape_Name="/Footer:1"/>`, where 'Footer' is the name of a global zone in your theme, and ShapeName is the name of your shape. Basically, just add a forward slash to the start of the zone name when you want to reference a global zone rather than a local one.

Comment: In reference to the "/xxxx" placement specification to place items in global zones instead of local zones, this seems to only work for placement.info files located in Themes (ie, it has no effect on placement.info files located in Modules, as of the time I'm writing this). Not sure if it's a bug or a design decision, but it's something to be wary of